# How do I avoid getting any chromatic aberration in my photographs?

Tags: lens, dslr, wavelength, chromatic-aberration

Another question is how to correct it ([suggested in proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265)), but

... **are there ways of avoiding it in the first place?**