# Remove violet glowing effect

Tags: product-photography, chromatic-aberration

I'm taking simple product photo on white background with two softboxes on sides. On some products (especially white), I get strange blue-violet glowing effect on edges:

[image]

[Link to larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GABZD.jpg)

Anyone knows what can cause it and how to fix?

Shooting with Nikon D3100, 18-105mm lense (22mm, ISO100, f/8, 1/25).

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly [chromatic aberrations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration)?  Are you getting this affect on only that lens or multiple? See [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/photographic-techniques-to-avoid-chromatic-aberration) question for some advice on how to minimize the affect.

Comment: @MitchGoshorn, thank you very much, looks like you're right, now I know what to search for.

Comment: Almost certainly chromatic aberration. Any decent RAW processor will get rid of it very quickly.

Comment: More specifically, this is lateral chromatic aberration: you can see that the outer (closer to the corner) edges are greenish and the inner ones are purplish.  This type of chromatic aberration is easier to correct during postprocessing: RAW converters will typically have an option for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [purple fringing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_fringing) and occurs either digitally during color-interpolation or optically when a lens does not focus all wave-lengths the same. The latter is  generally known as [chromatic aberration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration). It can be other colors than purple in that case.

In either case, you can correct the issue post-processing using chromatic aberration removal. Some cameras have that feature built-in which is quite effective but not perfect. It really depends on the model.

Adobe Lightroom, since version 4, offers a simple [tool to remove this](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2012/04/new-color-fringe-correction-controls.html). You can even sample from the fringe to have it remove the exact color. I have used it and can say it works quite well.